# UTF-8 unrecognised character

Tags: php, utf-8, smarty

Good morning,

I am new to developing and to using smarty.
I have a random character in my database which my smarty template does not recognise. The character is in the middle of the intended output, the output is not displayed and messes up the template from the point where the output should be displayed. The character is `’` (0xe28099).

I have used php's mb_detect_encoding and it says its UTF - 8.

Does anyone know if there is any way to get this character to display?

*update to original question

I have found that the first time the variable is output nothing appears but the data does appear on subsequent outputs?

Comment: Can you post more of that value containing that character?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. The value is like:  Matt D’Argo

Comment: Have you tried: `iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $text);` or `UTF-8 to UTF-8`? More about [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

Comment: As soon as you paste the character in a forum you lose the original encoding. You may post the output of `var_dump(bin2hex('’'));` as well.

Comment: Thanks @Duvdevan, I have tried iconv and the output still didn't appear on the first instance.

Comment: Thanks @Álvaro González , the output is: string 'e28099' (length=6)

Comment: FYI, `0xE2 0x80 0x99` is the correct UTF-8 encoding of [U+2019 (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm). Since I know nothing about Smarty there's not much else I can add, expect a suspect that part of your toolchain is not configured for multi-byte encodings.

Comment: Side note: `mb_detect_encoding()` does **not** do what most people think.

Comment: Since it is an extended character you need to ensure that the PHP page is rendered in UTF-8 charset, or another Unicode encoding. Check that.